# Javascript regEx to remove all parentheses except between special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, capturing-group

I need a regEx to remove all `(` and `)` from a string, except those between two @.

Example:

```
( [15] == @value 1@ || [15] == @value 2@ )  &&  ( [5] == @value 3 (ignore these)@ || [5] == @value 4@ )  ||  ( [2] == @value 5@ )
```

The string I need:

```
[15] == @value 1@ || [15] == @value 2@  &&  [5] == @value 3 (ignore these)@ || [5] == @value 4@  ||  [2] == @value 5@
```

I tried something with this non-capturing group to split with whitespaces except those between @ but could not find the way:

```
(?:@[^@]*@|\S)
```

I'm under pressure to solve this, any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: do you have to use regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this regex for matching:

```sh
\s*[()](?=(?:[^@]*@[^@]*@)*[^@]*$)\s*
```

And replace with just empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9vq6NQ/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `[()]`: Match `(` or `)`
- `(?=`: Start positive lookahead

  - `(?:[^@]*@[^@]*@)*`: Match 0 or more pairs of `@...@` substrings
  - `[^@]*`: Match 0 more of anything but `@`
  - `$`: End
- `)`: End positive lookahead
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces

Comment: Thanks! Works on most browsers but Safari, Im getting this error there: "Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name"

Comment: This should work in old browsers as I didn't use any lookbehind but I don't use safari

Comment: My bad, it was another regex causing the issue.